# Printing ÆØÅ (upper case) letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

I have tried to search quite a bit (and found some solutions that I think should have worked, but they don't...)

This is my basic test code:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
print('æøå')
print('ÆØÅ')
```

It prints æøå as expected however the upper case ÆØÅ gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\(removed)", line 3, in <module>
æøå
    print('�\x86�\x98�\x85')
  File "C:\(removed)", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x86' in position 1: character maps to <undefined> `
```

Looking up 8859-1 (I have also tried 8859-15) it says that both æøå and ÆØÅ is included, I am using Atom to do this, however failed on PyCharm with Anaconda too. Also Atom managed to print everything correctly when I imported a csv file with ÆØÅ in it. Is there another coding I could try perhaps?

Note: not encoding doesn't give an error, but I do get these symbols instead �, or some other weird symbol :).

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually saving the file as `latin-8859-1`? Writing that line at the top of the Python file is not enough. Your text editor must actually do it, too.

Comment: Yes? I have tried changing the encoding option in the bottom right corner in atom to, UTF-8, ISO 8859-1 and Auto Detect (gives either UTF-8 or Windows 1252) with more or less same result, either crash or the question mark. Changing to 8859-1 gave the question markes for both æøå and ÆØÅ.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else reads this I found a solution. Changing the coding to `# -*- coding: windows-1252 -*-` fixed my problem and correctly displayed boht æøå and ÆØÅ, still no idea why ISO-8859-1 failed to display ÆØÅ while æøå worked fine tho.